# Error loading jquery.min.js from googleapis.com in Iran

Tags: support, external-sources

I hope this won't be off-topic.
I know this is not a technical bug, but I am living in Iran and as you might know we are in sanction and google is blocked our request to CDN libraries. I recently get the 'Stackoverflow requires external java script from another domain which is blocked' error.

[image]

Since your site is international I was wondering if is it possible to load jquery from your site or another source which is not blocked in our country?

p.s: When I use antifilter or vpn programs (which change my ip to another country) everything is OK.

Comment: @AlE. The question is the same but the answer should be different. see the answer post

Comment: Have you tried a userscript which includes jquery for you?

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry I don't get the point